# open URL inside presented MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have an app that presents a MFMessageComposeViewController for sending a text message for a predefined number. The current user already has an SMS history with this number, so already existing SMS with this number show up in the composer. Some of this SMSs have links inside.

Problem is:

When I click on the link from my app message composer the link does nothing.
BUT when I open the SMS app, select the contact and click the links in old messages it opens in Safari.

Question is: is there any way I can handle the tap on the links inside an MFMessageComposeViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell this is not currently possible.

And you are also not aloud subclass. Since there are no other public messaging Apis you are out of luck on this one. - at least on this version of ios 7.

Comment: I though so, could this be submited as a bug? If you long press the link an action sheet shows up but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @augustos10 absolutely - file a radar bug and I will too, it's annoying and I use it in one of my apps also.